# Problemas com Arquivos de conta eletrônica de celular(febraban)

Tags: java, edi

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Não chega ser nem uma dúvida técnica, mas sim se alguém tem alguma luz do layout utilizado pela Empresa VIVO nos arquivos febraban.

No site da propria Febraban tem um layout, mas ele não é respeitado:

https://www.febraban.org.br/Acervo1.asp?id_texto=201&id_pagina=173&palavra=

Nas minhas pesquisas pela web muita gente tem problemas com esses arquivos.

Caso não exista um layout alguém sabe onde posso bater os dados e descobri 'no olho' o que é o que?

Essa imagem é um exemplo de como esta definido no layout fornecido pela Febraban

Mas de cara o arquivo que recebi omite o identificador único e inverte varias posições

```
000000000000120160607VIVO S/A CE    CEXXXXXXXXX    CXXXX DE AXX DOS FXXX DO XXXXXXXX    05810000000103 2058747458     052016    2016052820160508
```

Comment: Prezado, é um arquivo posicional certo? Não é respeitado? poderia nos dar mais detalhes? Sua pergunta é sim interessante!

Comment: Adicionei a imagem referente ao Header e alinha de Header que recebi. Só que isso se repere para todas as linhas :/

Comment: Também tive problemas com esse formato. No Item referente a serviço (04), ele não esta de acordo com layout. O tipo 0 Header, e o 1 Conta resumo, não tive problemas, a versão do layout que uso é do ano 2000, versão 2!

Comment: @LuizAugusto tem como você me passar as informações desse layout que você usa.

Comment: Esse problema já é bem antigo. As companhias telefônicas - não é só a Vivo - não respeitam este padrão. E pelo visto não adianta nada reclamar...